# Unexpected keyword 'import' in WebPack Django and Vue.js project

Tags: django, webpack, vue.js

I have a simple project where I am using Django, Webpack and Vue.js. When I build a static bundle upon load it seems like my bundle is not compiled correctly.  I get an error in JavaScript console:

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'import'
    (anonymous function) (main-dd2bbbf09bf9a252a3c7.js:47)
```

I tried to keep my webpack.config.js really simple:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');


module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './frontend/js/main',
  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./frontend/bundles/'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ],
  },
}
```

.babelrc looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false }]
  ]
}
```

main.js (which ultimately blows up) is simple:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the node_modules folder and running `npm install` again.

Comment: Yes. Doesn't help 

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the issue was the version of the webpack and related libraries.  The full solution is done and posted here: https://github.com/mikebz/djangovue

```
{
  "name": "djangovue",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Mike Borozdin",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=prod webpack --progress --config webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev webpack --progress --config webpack.config.js --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "node-libs-browser": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-loader": "^12.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```